# Is it possible to mix different images into a single one using ImageMagick?

Tags: image-processing, command-line, imagemagick

I have different images in different .png files like the following:

[image]

I'd like to find a command line tool that allows me to mix all those images into a single one while generating a new .png file:

[image]

I know that using `ImageMagick` we can manipulate images from the command line in many useful ways. I've looked for questions under the imagemagick tag here on stackoverflow but I didn't find anything similar to what I need and the man pages of the ImageMagick tools like `convert` and `compare` are extremely extensive. **Is it even possible to solve using ImageMagick? If so, how can I do it?**

---

**Edit:**

Individual images files:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Post your individual images and I can show you how to do it. Or see https://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#convert. If you are using ImageMagick 7, change convert to magick.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks! I've edited my question adding the individual files on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick 6, you can do the following to composite each image onto the circle.

Unix Syntax:

```
convert circle.png \
cloud.png -geometry +60+10 -compose over -composite \
phone.png -geometry +40+100 -compose over -composite \
arrow.png -geometry +120+100 -compose over -composite \
result.png
```

Windows Syntax:

```
convert.exe circle.png \
cloud.png -geometry +60+10 -compose over -composite ^
phone.png -geometry +40+100 -compose over -composite ^
arrow.png -geometry +120+100 -compose over -composite ^
result.png
```

[image]

If using ImageMagick 7, change convert to magick. On Windows be careful as there is a Windows convert.exe. You may want to rename the ImageMagick convert.exe to something else and use that above.

The \ and ^ are line feed characters so that the command can be written on multiple lines. If you make this all one line, then remove those characters.